# Select row by level of a factor

Tags: r, subset, r-factor

I have a data frame, `df2`,  containing observations grouped by a ID `factor` that I would like to subset. I have used another function to identify which rows *within each factor group* that I want to select. This is shown below in `df`:

```
df <- data.frame(ID = c("A","B","C"),
                 pos = c(1,3,2))
df2 <- data.frame(ID = c(rep("A",5), rep("B",5), rep("C",5)),
                  obs = c(1:15))
```

In `df`, `pos` corresponds to the index of the row that I want to select within the factor level mentioned in `ID`, not in the whole dataframe `df2`.I'm looking for a way to select the rows for each `ID` according to the right index (so their row number within the level of each factor of `df2`).

So, in this example, I want to select the first value in `df2` with `ID == 'A'`, the third value in `df2` with `ID == 'B'` and the second value in `df2` with `ID == 'C'`.

This would then give me:

```
df3 <- data.frame(ID = c("A", "B", "C"),
                  obs = c(1, 8, 12))
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's the base R solution:

```
df2$pos <- ave(df2$obs, df2$ID, FUN=seq_along)
merge(df, df2)
  ID pos obs
1  A   1   1
2  B   3   8
3  C   2  12
```

If `df2` is sorted by `ID`, you can just do `df2$pos <- sequence(table(df2$ID))` for the first line.

Comment: Good idea. Instead of making an intermediate data set, though, you could do `df2$pos <- sequence(lengths(split(df2$ID,df2$ID)))` and then just `merge(df,df2)` I'd argue that that way isn't much uglier than dplyr.

Comment: This answer as [currently edited](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/32210919/2) assumes that the entries in `df2` are presorted by ID.

Comment: @A.Webb Seems like a reasonable assumption, but I'll put back the original version (before I edited it) that covers the case you're concerned with.

Comment: @Frank Post your own version with assumptions stated if you like, but I wouldn't edit another answer's code esp. given the additional assumption.

Comment: @A.Webb Eh, a bit late now, but that's good advice; thanks. I edited it in here, since it seemed to follow the same idea (to me, since it's about creating a `pos` column before merging).

Comment: I feel unworthy; this solution as edited is more @Frank's work than mine, and is much more elegant. I always forget about the `ave` function.

Comment: @user295691 That's okay. I wouldn't have thought of it without seeing your answer and so didn't feel justified in posting a new one. Plenty of sympathy votes accrued to my answer below anyways, perhaps thanks to my edits here :)

Answer (score 11):

**dplyr**

```
library(dplyr)

merge(df,df2) %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  filter(row_number() == pos) %>%
  select(-pos)

#   ID obs
# 1  A   1
# 2  B   8
# 3  C  12
```

**base R**

```
df2m <- merge(df,df2)
do.call(rbind, 
  by(df2m, df2m$ID, function(SD) SD[SD$pos[1], setdiff(names(SD),"pos")]) 
)
```

`by` splits the merged data frame `df2m` by `df2m$ID` and operates on each part; it returns results in a list, so they must be `rbind`ed together at the end. Each subset of the data (associated with each value of `ID`) is filtered by `pos` and deselects the `"pos"` column using normal data.frame syntax.

**data.table** suggested by @DavidArenburg in a comment

```
library(data.table)

setkey(setDT(df2),"ID")[df][, 
  .SD[pos[1L], !"pos", with=FALSE]
, by = ID]
```

The first part -- `setkey(setDT(df2),"ID")[df]` -- is the merge. After that, the resulting table is split `by = ID`, and each Subset of Data, `.SD` is operated on. `pos[1L]` is subsetting in the normal way, while `!"pos", with=FALSE` corresponds to dropping the `pos` column.

See @eddi's answer for a better data.table approach.

Comment: Also maybe `library(data.table) ; setkey(setDT(df2), "ID")[df][, .SD[pos[1L]], by = ID]` or something similar.

Comment: Your solution seems to be the most elegant... But I cannot install dplyr. I know it's none of your concern but still, I wanted to say it here so you don't think I've been ignoring the top post.

Comment: Running the dplyr solution on my whole database, I get this error message: Error: 'names' attribute [26127] must be the same length as the vector [49]. The base R does not work either : Error in `[.default`(xj, i) : invalid subscript type 'list'. Or the data.table : Error in setDT(datatestE, "IDPAT") : 
  Argument 'giveNames' to 'setDT' must be logical TRUE/FALSE. I know it's something to do with the structure of my data though.

Comment: @user2092517 Ok, that's interesting, but I don't really have any ideas how to resolve it. If the base R solution in the other answer works, I'd say just go ahead with that.

Comment: Is there a spelling mistake (bracket?) in the data.table solution? Also, I'd appreciate a short commentary on how to base R and data.table solutions work (I can read the dplyr version immediately, but to understand the other two, I'll have to read a few help pages first.)

Comment: @maj Yes, thanks for catching the typo. I'll add some explanation.

Comment: In the spirit of dplyr, we could use the dplyr `inner_join`, and defer the merge -- `df2 %>% group_by(ID) %>% mutate(pos=row_number()) %>% inner_join(df) %>% select(-pos)`

Comment: @user295691 Yeah. I think that fits more naturally under your answer, though; you can add a dplyr answer in addition to the base one. The approaches in this answer are all of the "merge first, ask questions later" form; while yours (including that comment) are "create a `pos` column and merge".

Answer (score 7):

Using `data.table` version 1.9.5+:

```
setDT(df2)[df, .SD[pos], by = .EACHI, on = 'ID']
```

which merges on `ID` column, then selects the `pos` row for each of the rows of `df`.

Comment: Or just `setkey(setDT(df2), "ID")[df, .SD[pos], by = .EACHI]` without the devel version